# Null value in KStream.map causing IllegalArgumentException: Payload must not be null

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-messaging

### Problem Description:

I'm creating a spring cloud Kafka stream application. I have one input topic and one output topic and I'm trying to apply a KStream Key-Value transform operation for the input topic using KStream.map function
The problem if I have a transformed value as **null**, the function throws IllegalArgumentException
**My questions are:**
*1: Reason for the exception?* Although in the documentation says: "Input records with a null key or a null value are ignored"
*2: Best practices to handle exceptions in stateless/stateful operations*? Should a try/catch surround the whole processing plan will be enough? Or I should have a try/catch inside every transformation functions (ex. filter, map, join, reduce)?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

### Application Config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name:kafka-streams-test
  cloud.stream:
    kafka.streams:
      binder:
        brokers: localhost:9093
        configuration:
          commit.interval.ms: 1000
          security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
          sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
          sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
        serdeError: logAndContinue
      bindings:
        streams-words-input:
          consumer:
            application-id: Input-Words
        streams-words-output:
          consumer:
            application-id: Output-Words
    bindings:
      streams-words-input:
        destination: streams-words-input
      streams-words-output:
        destination: streams-words-output
```

### Sample Code:

```
@StreamListener()
@SendTo("streams-words-output")
public KStream<String, Long> createWords(
    @Input("streams-words-input") final KStream<String, String> wordsInput){
    return wordsInput
            .map((key,value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, null));
}
```

### Exception Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Payload must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder.<init>(MessageBuilder.java:57)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(MessageBuilder.java:179)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsMessageConversionDelegate.lambda$serializeOnOutbound$0(KafkaStreamsMessageConversionDelegate.java:86)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsMessageConversionDelegate$$Lambda$743/1725151361.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.AbstractStream$2.apply(AbstractStream.java:87)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:40)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPassThrough$KStreamPassThroughProcessor.process(KStreamPassThrough.java:33)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:122)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamBranch$KStreamBranchProcessor.process(KStreamBranch.java:48)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:302)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:964)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you see is coming from Spring Messaging long standing rule - "*there are no Message with null payload*". In other words there is no message to be sent if there is nothing to communicate.

That said, there is obviously an issue with KStream and how it handles this condition, so I'd suggest to raise an issue in [Kafka binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka). Meanwhile you can easily add a `filter` operation to your pipeline to filter out the nulls.

Comment: Kafka records with a `null` `value()` are considered tombstone records (used with compacted topics). There is a "special" payload `KafkaNull.INSTANCE` which we use when we wish to send a tombstone to kafka. The `KafkaStreamsMessageConversionDelegate` should do that translation when a `null` `value()` is encountered.

Comment: It is indeed a bug that this exception is thrown and needs to be fixed in the binder. With that said, if you can upgrade your app to the 3.0.0 line (`Horsham` Release train of Spring Cloud Stream), then you won't get this exception since by default the conversions are done by Kafka Streams `Serdes`. If you want to do the message conversion in Spring, you have to opt-in for that. I suggest upgrading first if possible, but we will fix it in the binder. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the helping comments. I'm using cloud-stream-binder-kafka 2.1.2 version because of the dependencies on spring boot 2.1.5 so maybe I will not be able to upgrade to 3.0.0.
Actually I pointed the bug in the Kafka binder and I have applied the filter to solve the issue temporarily.